# repeating entry blogs on my wordpress? how to fix?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am confused in the coding of my css sheet for my website template. If you go to [www.ohepic.com](http://www.ohepic.com) you can see the first ten entry blogs... then next time also it repeats again with the older ones....

how can I prevent this repeat from happening? Can someone help me in finding which css sheet is affecting this? And how do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a catagory then you may try this code. it may help

```
 <?php   
        $args=array(
          'cat' => ***,
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page' => 10,
          'caller_get_posts'=> 1
          );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
          echo 'List of Posts';
          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
           <?php
          endwhile;
        }
    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    ?>
```

Note : `***` is Catagory_id